# How to calculate date in the past from given date (also in past) using "date -d 'xx/xx/xxxx - xx' "

Tags: bash, shell, date

I have a input date:

> 01-01-2019 08:30:00

And I would like to back it in time by:

> 2hours 10minutes

So the new date should be like:

> 01-01-2019 06:20

---

I have tried commands:

(1)`date -d "2019-01-01 08:30:00 + 1hour"`
which return: `Tue Jan 1 09:30:00 STD 2019` (ok, but seems to be lucky shot)

(2)`date -d "2019-01-01 08:30:00 - 1hour"`
which return: `Tue Jan 1 11:30:00 STD 2019` that means +3hours (wrong)

(3)`date -d "2019-01-01 08:30:00 + 3hours"`
which return: `Tue Jan 1 07:30:00 STD 2019` that means -1hours (wrong)

(4)`date -d "2019-01-01 08:30:00 + 2minutes"`
which return: `Tue Jan 1 07:31:00 STD 2019` that means -59minutes (wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to explicitly mention your timezone:

```
$ TZ=STD date -d '2019-01-01 08:30:00 STD + 1 hour'
Tue Jan  1 09:30:00 STD 2019
$ TZ=STD date -d '2019-01-01 08:30:00 STD - 3 hour'
Tue Jan  1 05:30:00 STD 2019
$ TZ=STD date -d '2019-01-01 08:30:00 STD + 2 minutes'
Tue Jan  1 08:32:00 STD 2019
```

This seems to alleviate `date`s confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The is only one most reliable way of doing that:

```
date -d "@$(( $(date -d '2019-01-01 08:30:00' +%s) - ( 2 * 60 + 10 ) * 60 ))"
```

First convert to seconds since epoch.

Then subtract the time you want.

Then use `date` to format the output.